# How to pass self object to Global variable (Django views)

Tags: python, django, performance

I'm writing [hellban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_banning) functionality for my Django-based web-app. In various class-based view methods, I trigger some functionality **if user is in ban list**. Since I'm repeating this comparison in several views, I decided to turn it into a global variable - outside of any class-based views - thusly:

```
isbanned = HellBanList.objects.filter(condemned_id=self.request.user.id).exists()
```

Unfortunately, I ran into the error: `name 'self' is not defined`, i.e. self object is not available outside class-based views. I get similar results for `request.user` and `user` too.

Is there any workaround for `self.request.user` that I can use to calculate such a global variable (that works for both authenticated and unauthenticated users)? My objective is to calculate only ONCE whether the requesting user is part of the hellban list, and then use that information wherever required.

OR should I refrain from doing that due to problems I'm not foreseeing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all having global variable is not thread safe. Just imagine two requests processed at the same time. Second one could overwrite `isbanned` before first one is finished, leading to first request being incorrectly processed.

If I were you I would write [middleware class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/) that evaluates whether user is banned only once per request. And then store this information in a request:

```
class CalculateUserBannedMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.user_banned = HellBanList.objects.filter(condemned_id=request.user.id).exists()
```

The middleware class needs to be defined after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` in order to be able to access `request.user` attribute:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'myapp.CalculateUserBannedMiddleware'
```

And in the rest of your code you could use `request.user_banned` to check if current user is banned. This way the flag is calculated only once per request.

---

EDIT:

You can even make the solution smarter if `user_banned` is calculated lazily. This way you do not have any overhead for requests that do not need this flag.

One way to achieve lazy evaluation is to use object with `__bool__` method (Python 3) or `__nonzero__` method (Python 2).

Example implementation for Python 3:

```
class LazyUserBannedFlag(object):

    user_banned = None

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def __bool__(self):
        if self.user_banned is None:
            user_id = self.request.user.id
            self.user_banned = HellBanList.objects.filter(condemned_id=user_id).exists()
        return self.user_banned


class CalculateUserBannedMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.user_banned = LazyUserBannedFlag(request)
```

Comment: Hey Dawid, could you amend something in your answer for completeness:?`user` is not defined in the middleware code you've written. That should be `request.user` right?

Comment: You are right, it should be `request.user`. I fixed that. After some thought I also come up with even smarter solution.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't count on `request` to do the query. You should write a util functionality with the parameter as user, like this:

```
def is_banned(user):
    return HellBanList.objects.filter(condemned_id=user.id).exists()
```

Then when you need to check, do:

```
user_is_banned = is_banned(self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip, Shane! Question: I was hoping I'd do an "exists()" DB query *just once*, and then use it everywhere. In your solution, will that goal be achieved, or will it do a new DB query every time I calculate whether `user_is_banned`?

Comment: It's going to do multiple times, but I believe it's a cheap database operation to do `exists()`. If you REALLY want to save the result, you need to use either django `session` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/ or in memory tools like `redis`.